# mysql - select where have all array values

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table:

```
ID    |    Product_ID    |    Filter_ID
1          1                  8
2          1                  9
3          2                  10
```

I also have php array contains filters to be checked:

```
$arr = (8,9,10);
```

Now, How to make sure that Product_ID (1) has all filters that in $arr ?

Comment: I don't know to do it actually

Comment: use `SELECT * FROM table WHERE filter_id IN (". implode(',', $arr).")`

Comment: Your question is not correct in compare with best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only those product_id which have all 3 filter_ids, try this:

```
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, Product_ID FROM `test`.`test` WHERE Filter_ID IN (".implode(', ', $arr).") GROUP BY Product_ID HAVING total >= ". sizeof($arr);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e949f/7/0

**@edit**

If you need to know only if a specific Product_ID have all 3 Filter_IDS:

```
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, Product_ID FROM `test`.`test` WHERE Filter_ID IN (".implode(', ', $arr).") and Product_ID = 1 GROUP BY Product_ID HAVING total >= ". sizeof($arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr = [8, 9, 10];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `Filter_ID` IN (".implode(', ', $arr).")";
```

Comment: this may help! let me check

Comment: `$arr = [8, 9, 10];` may need to be `$arr = array('8', '9', '10');` depending on PHP version.

Comment: array() - is old declaration of array.

Comment: Yes I know. But some still use older versions of PHP and is worth noting.

Comment: sorry guys, That's because I'm coding many languages you know :)